# Apache Virtual Hosts serves the vhost NOT matched

Tags: apache, proxy, xampp, virtual-machine, vhosts

I set up an Apache Server with two Virtual Hosts and it has a very weird behaviour. I have a normal webserver, that should be server in all cases, except given the case, that the domain name is "biblio.name" or "biblio-intra.name", which should be redirected to a virtual machine located on my laptop, serving another webservice on Linux. On my laptop I use xampp for the Apache Server. I have the following "httpd-vhosts.conf" in my apache/conf/extra folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName sis.name/
    ServerAlias *
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
    ServerName biblio.name/
    ServerAlias biblio-intra.name/
</VirtualHost>
```

So I expected it to redirect all requests to "biblio.name" and serve the rest as normal. However, it didn't!
When I enter my static ip-adress (assigned from the router) in the browser, I get served htdocs as normal, perfectly fine. When I enter biblio.name:8080 I also get normally served the virtual machine as expected (obviously, since 8080 automatically uses the redirect rule of the virtual machine.) However, when I type "sis.name" it redirects me to the virtual machine and when I type "biblio.name" it serves me from the htdocs.
I never experienced a behaviour like that and I don't get, why it serves the opposite host of the one supposed to.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I don't know (anymore), all my apache vhost configurations have the same value for `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`. Also the `/` in it seems odd. You can try listing `biblio-intra.name` as second option, but it should at first repeat the value from `ServerName`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName   sis.name
    ServerAlias  sis.name
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName        biblio.name
    ServerAlias       biblio.name biblio-intra.name
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPass         "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
</VirtualHost>
```